# How can i create a slider which removes blur class on mobile hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I want to create a slider as shown in image below.
[Demo image for idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITpDx.png)

basically all 4 boxes are blurred and last box is clear as it has mobile case hover.

What I want to do is when i scroll mobile to left, each box on each case comes will clear and other are blurred.

I have tried a lot of sliders to create like this, but i failed to create like this.

please help.
please see the attached image for reference.

Comment: mobile hover? you mean touch don't you? :)

Comment: Moreover the "image below" is not here. And without neither code nor image it's kinda hard :p .

Comment: I forgot to attach an image, Please see the attached image for reference